# Changing editors (lowercase) to Editors (italicized) in BibTeX style similar to apalike

Tags: bibtex, custom-bib

I am trying to make BibTeX conform to the standards of a particular journal (they are quite similar to APA). I built a custom .bst file using the lovely package custom-bib, which worked very well except for two things.

For a book with no authors but editors, my .bst file produces

> Cook, E. and Kariukstis, L. (editors), 1990. *Methods of Dendrochronology: Applications in the Environmental Sciences*, Kluwer Academic Publishers

but I want it to produce

> Cook, E. and Kariukstis, L. (*Editors*), 1990. Methods of Dendrochronology: Applications in the Environmental Sciences, Kluwer Academic Publishers

Note the difference in the (Editors) and the lack of title italicization.
I understand this isn't reproducible without the actual .bst file, but I am hoping someone could point me in the proper direction. Perhaps the following functions are relevant. BST syntax is pretty unintelligible to me offhand.

```
FUNCTION {bbl.editors}
{ "editors" }

FUNCTION {format.editors}
{editor "editor" format.names duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      " " *
      get.bbl.editor
   "(" swap$ * ")" *
      *
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f{.}.}"
      format.name$
      bibinfo bibinfo.check
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              numnames #2 >
                { "," * }
                'skip$
              if$
              t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal *
                }
                {
                  bbl.and
                  space.word * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
  } if$
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I see the bst file contains a function called `bbl.editors`; try changing its argument from `"editors"` to `"\textit{Editors}"`. Same deal for the function called `bbl.editor`.

Comment: Mico, I tried that and nothing changed :(

Comment: I removed and re-added the citation from the .bib file and now it worked. I don't know why that helped..? Thank you though!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved by the comments.